# custom Post content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

As you know, the following code publishes the latest content in a group in its WordPress

```
<?php
            $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1&cat=172');
            while ($my_query->have_posts()):
            $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
            ?>
```

I want to make changes to this code، So that the last article in a group is not displayed and 
, And the pre-final content of the same group will be displayed.
thank u

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at the **offset and order parameters**.
I'm guessing that the snapshot in your question is what you call a "group"...
Depending on what you call the last article (last published or first published) you might want to change the order from 'DESC' to 'ASC'.

```
<?php $query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => '172', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'offset' => '1', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

gl.

**EDIT:** Just an idea... You could also simply go with pure CSS and targeting your last post with `:last-child` ... see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child